# cannot create tag

Tags: git, cygwin, cruisecontrol.net

I have a build machine with CruiseControl.Net running Windows 2008R2. Sources are in git repository. CruiseControl uses **cygwin** to access git repository. Everything works well except tagging. I want to tag every successful build, so here is part of **ccnet.config**:

```
<sourcecontrol type="git">
    <repository>git://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Project</repository>
    <executable>C:\cygwin\bin\git</executable>
    <branch>projectName/branchToBuild</branch>
    <workingDirectory>Sources</workingDirectory>
    <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
    <tagOnSuccess>true</tagOnSuccess>
    <tagCommitMessage>CCNet Build {0}</tagCommitMessage>
    <tagNameFormat>project/builds/v{0}</tagNameFormat>
    <committerName>CCNet</committerName>
</sourcecontrol>
```

But build fails with error:

```
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: error: unable to create temporary sha1 filename : No such file or directory

error: unable to write tag file
. Process command: C:\cygwin\bin\git tag -a -m "CCNet Build 6.2.18.0" project/builds/v6.2.18.0
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ProcessSourceControl.Execute(ProcessInfo processInfo)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Git.GitCreateTag(String tagName, String tagMessage, IIntegrationResult result)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Git.LabelSourceControl(IIntegrationResult result)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Build(IIntegrationResult result)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)
```

What could be wrong? If I execute the same command from command line, everything works fine.

Thanks!

Solved by adding this to msbuild project file:

```
<Exec Command='C:\cygwin\bin\git tag -a -m "CCNet Build" project/builds/v$(CCNetLabel)' ContinueOnError="true"/>
<Exec Command='C:\cygwin\bin\git push origin tag project/builds/v$(CCNetLabel)' ContinueOnError="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the user that is running the ccnet service does not have write access to the repository.

Comment: It has write access, because the directory was created by him. And all the files were pulled and checked out by him.

Comment: I don't know much about the cygwin version of git (maybe a / or \ issue). You may want to try msysgit that is working well on windows. I'm also using this during the development of the git source control task in CCNet

Comment: I had another problem with msysgit. It hangs on pushes.

Comment: Have you tested to rune the command (the one from the ccnet logs) in the same working directory and under the same user the ccnet service runs? This error message is from git directly and not an ccnet issue. It really looks like some path separator issue or permission issue.